# Scope of a variable being changed locally in a Function_ python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

This function works correctly and is giving me the exact value of final_list when I am printing it. [image: a]

But when I decided to print final_list separately to check if the value is getting changed globally, I find out that the value of final_list is being changed locally[image]

What to do so that final_list gets changed globally?

Comment: Put your code here. Give the expected output.

Comment: When you have the code in the text also then why do you post the screenshots?

Answer (score 0):

Use the keyword global in the function to make it a global variable.The changes within a function will be affected globally .

> global *variable*

make these changes
 global final_list in line 2 of your function.

Answer (score 0):

As lists are [`mutable`](https://www.mygreatlearning.com/blog/understanding-mutable-and-immutable-in-python/#M&I) in Python. Don't add the line `final_list = [ ]` in your function and then run the code.

It will change the `final_list`.